# Swift Model Class - Use of undeclared type - Xcode 7 beta

Tags: xcode6, swift2

Despite several questions on the same topic, I'd have to re-ask this since none of those questions seem to cover it. I have an error in Xcode 7 beta 3 where I get a "Use of undeclared type" error in my data model. Here's a screenshot, please ignore the property names since this is a quick test project to see how [OCMapper](https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper) works with Swift 2, Alamofire.

[image]

I've tried Clean + Rebuild, Clean build folder + rebuild, ensured the file actually is included in my target's compile sources list, deleted derived data etc. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property does matter. Change your variable name to not the same with the class name like so because it has conflicts and the compiler does not know it should be class name or variable name:

```
var person: Person?
var doctor: Doctor?
var address: Address?
```

Comment: Oh yeah, nice catch. Thank you, it was driving me nuts!